# How to superscript in a link

Tags: html

```css
.project-link {
font-family:Arial; 
display:inline-block;
color:#FFF;
font-size:5vw;
white-space:nowrap;
text-decoration:underline;
margin-right: 3%;
line-height:120%;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<a class="project-link" id="one" href="#modal1">Maru Speaker Design <sup> (1) </sup> </a>
<
```

I'm trying to get (1) to be superscript.

*EDIT* https://jsfiddle.net/v1jn1nus/

Added pic with Arial font.

I just don't understand. It works in the fiddle too...

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't change your code when I added the snippet. When I run it, the `(1)` is superscriped. Do you have any conflicting css attached?

Comment: And that appears to work for me, when I run your snippet. What doesn't work for you?

Comment: Huh. I updated OP with the accompanying css.

Comment: I edited your question again (without changing your code). I only added a black background to observe the `(1)`, and once again, it works fine.

Comment: Still showing up as superscript. Can you include a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: It's possible that your font, `NeuzeitGroteskTOT-Reg` is changing the subscript. Does it work when you remove the font-family?

Comment: Edited OP w/ fiddle and pic

Comment: My best guess would be your fonts do not support Superscript. Now, they are working on here (and JSFiddle) because they can't find your font, and therefore it is defaulting to something like Arial. To see if that is the problem, perhaps change your font on your website to Arial and see if it works.

Comment: The code for `.project-link` in the fiddle is different from the code here in the question.

Comment: @MichaelJones @DaveChen I don't think it's a problem with the font.  I don't know what `NeuzeitGroteskTOT-Reg` looks like, but the text in the screenshot appears to be in Cambria.  In fact, in the Fiddle, the font is set to Cambria there, so I don't know why it's different here in the question.  Anyway, Cambria's a standard Windows font, so it's not like it's obscure.  And it works in Cambria on my machine.

Comment: So to clarify, you are using `NeuzeitGroteskTOT-Reg` on your website? If so, is that font working on your website? I think that is the problem, the reason why `Cambria` is showing superscript is because that font supports superscript, `NeuzeitGroteskTOT-Reg` ***DOES NOT***.

Comment: I've tried just going back to a default Arial font. But it still doesn't superscript. I don't think the font is the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's `vertical-align:super;` so check if your style do not reset vertical-align on that element.

Check this:

```css
.project-link {
font-family:Arial; 
display:inline-block;
color:#FFF;
font-size:5vw;
white-space:nowrap;
text-decoration:underline;
margin-right: 3%;
line-height:120%;
}

.project-link > span { vertical-align:super; }

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<a class="project-link" id="one" href="#modal1">Maru Speaker Design <span> (1) </span> </a>
<
```

Comment: How to remove the underline of the superscripted item?